# How to use multiple localhosts

Tags: windows, url, hosts, browser

On my local development machine (Windows 7), I am using IIS and XAMPP to develop websites. Because it is unclear when I have multiple websits running, I am tried to rewrite the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc). I added this following line of code

```
127.0.0.1/joomla       joomla
```

Navigating my browser (I tried it with IE and FF) to 127.0.0.1/joomla works fine, but just typing in "joomla" won't work. I get immediately redirected to Google (i.e. http://www.google.com/search?q=joomla&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). Also specifying other ports doesn't work (for example: "localhost:8080 someproject" for IIS).

Is there a reason why it won't work? Are there other solutions which also accomplish my "problem" (easier handling with dozen of local running websites, i.e. "more readable URLs")?

Comment: You mention that you are using both IIS and Apache (the A in XAMPP). Are they listening on two different ports, or is only one of the two actually working? XAMPP is designed to be a self-contained Apache/MySQL/PHP stack for development/experimentation purposes and I have never heard of anyone integrating it with IIS.

Comment: Yea, there's no integration of the two. They're separate, fully contained web server platforms. I'm wondering if he has a site running on port 80 in both platforms? That would cause one or the other to not function.

Comment: Did this help you, System?

Answer (score 7):

Don't put the slash. You can define multiple host names for 127.0.0.1, but it's done in this format:

```
127.0.0.1      hostname
127.0.0.1      joomla
127.0.0.1      thatotherwebsite
```

Once you do the entries in the hosts file, that's all you should need to do. Afterwards, return to your browser, type in the name of the site you want, and good to go.

PS - You'll also need to be running these websites on [IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) that will allow you to define hostname binding per website. Then your web server will deliver the correct site for the name provided. The links provide information for both platforms about how to accomplish this.

Comment: The requirement for hostname binding is not a specific reason to use IIS.

Comment: I said IIS or something similar. He's running a Windows OS, so there's really no reason to download an extra tool when IIS is built in.

Answer (score 3):

DNS *only* maps domain names to IP addresses. It doesn't know anything about file paths.

In your hosts file, you can map the name "joomla" to 127.0.0.1 and then configure *Apache* to handle requests for "http://joomla/" however you like.

Comment: You do see that he said at the top of his question that he is using IIS right?

Comment: Oh dear, you're right. The question indicates use of both IIS and Apache... but listening on which ports? Hmm.

Comment: The listening ports would be defined in IIS as well. The modifications to the hosts file would have no bearing on that. (PS - It just dawned on me the A in XAMPP) :)